# Error in A First Course in Probability, Sheldon Ross (p. 24)

Tags: probability

The following quote is from *A First Course in Probability, Sheldon Ross, ch. 2, p. 24.*

> For any two events E and F, if all of the outcomes in E are also in F, then we say that E is contained in F, or E is a subset of F, and write E $\subset$  F (…). **Thus, if E $\subset$ F, then the occurrence of E implies the occurrence of F**.

In this case, doesn’t **the occurrence of F implies the occurrence of E**, and not the other way around?

Comment: The comments beat me to it. If $\omega \in E$ is an event, then $\omega \in F$ as well. It follows from the definition of subset.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is correct as written. Try with some examples. Suppose your outcome space is the roll of a die, and let $E$ be the event "rolling a six" and let $F$ be the event "rolling an even number." Then $E \subset F$ and the occurrence of "rolling a six" implies the occurrence of "rolling an even number."

Answer (score 1):

No. As E is contained in F, if E occurs, F definitely occurs. On the other hand, if F occurs, there may be a part of F that is not E, so we can not say that E definitely occurs.

Note: the textbook has *many* errors (it's the one we're using in my undergrad stats class too)